# Css Is Picking Up Wrong Class

Tags: css

I have a table element

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="nicktable">
```

In my css class I have 2 classes

```
#nicktable
{
  background-color: Maroon;
}
```

and

```
table
{
    font-size: 1em !important;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border: none;

}
```

I want the table to use the nicktable css, but its using the table css. How do I resolve this?

Comment: It's using both of them, and as neither overwrites the other they are being combined. Change the CSS of `#nicktable` to overwrite what is being set in the global `table`

Comment: whats a better way to tell the table element I wanna use just nicktable class?

Comment: Have you traced styles using firebug or similar? An id selector has higher specificity so should always take precedence over a tag selector. In the rule above the exception would be the font-size as it is tagged as important.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/RPzah/

Comment: For the record, your CSS contains two **rules**, not classes - one rule is for element with ID "nicktable" - no matter if it's `<div>` or `<table>` or anything else, and the other rule is for all the table tags no matter what's their ID or class.

Comment: @Nick if your intention is to "ignore" the rule set for `table` in the CSS you're out of luck.. all tables will be affected. Most you can do is "override" it in the other rule e.g. `#nicktable { font-size: 2em !important; }` this for example should override the table rule and make the font `2em` in size only for that specific table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those CSS rules will apply to your table (at the same time). `table { }` rules will be applied to any `<table>` element and the `#nicktable {}` rules will be applied only to an element with an ID of `nicktable`. If you don't want the `table { }` rules to apply to all tables, you can put them in a class such as `.mytable {}` and then only apply that to the tables you want. For example:

*CSS*

```
#nicktable {
  background-color: Maroon;
}
.mytable {
    font-size: 1em !important;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
```

*HTML*

`<table id="nicktable" class="mytable">` This will have both styles applied.
`<table id="nicktable">` This will have only `background-color: Maroon;` applied.
`<table class="mytable">` This will have only styles from `.mytable { }` applied.

**Edit**

You can also override the properties from `table {}` in `#nicktable {}` by specifying them again with new values. For example:

```
#nicktable {
    background-color: Maroon;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Since the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of `#nicktable {}` is higher than `table {}`, it will take precedence. Be careful when using `!important` however.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is using both selectors (not classes), because your table matches both selectors.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, nicktable is an id, maybe you used this more than once?
otherwise I see no error here...

Answer (score 0):

Use .nicktable and class="nicktable" instead. If you still need the ID for other purposes, keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a CSS class:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="maroon">

table
{
    font-size: 1em !important;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border: none;
}

.maroon
{
  background-color: Maroon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Residuum is correct. Your browser is applying the table style and then adding the id selector #nicktable. You can override the table style by including of the elements in nicktable.

Here's a good [article about CSS specificity](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c/).